# Dimension mismatch in subset expression in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I am very new to in bayesian analysis and I was trying to practice with an example from tidytuesday (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-03-29/sports.csv)

I have set my model but when trying to run it the following error message appears:

*Error in jags.model(textConnection(jags.script_with), data = dataset,  :
RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 5.
Dimension mismatch in subset expression of y*

Below my approach:

```
Sports2 =
  bind_rows(
    sports_clean %>%
      select(year, institution_name, sports, 
             participants = partic_women,
             revenue = rev_women,
             expenditure = exp_women) %>%
      mutate(gender=1), #women
    sports_clean %>%
      select(year, institution_name, sports, 
             participants = partic_men,
             revenue = rev_men,
             expenditure = exp_men) %>%
      mutate(gender=0) #men
  ) %>% na.omit
```

An example row of the dataset:

| Year | institution_name | sports | participants | revenue | expenditure | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | Alabama A&M Uni | Soccer | 21 | 410717 | 432648 | 1 |

```
#modeling with regression
set.seed(123)

model_with =
  lm(expenditure ~ gender + participants, data=Sports2)

model_with

#dataset for jags model
dataset = list(x=Sports2[,c(4,7)], y=Sports2[,6], n=nrow(Sports2))


#estimation coefficients
dataset$b_guess = model_with$coefficients

#Model
jags.script_with =
  "
model{
  #likelihood
  for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    mu[i] = intercept + participants*x[i,1]
  }
  #prioirs
  intercept ~ dnorm(bgues[1], 0.1)
  participants ~ dnorm(b_guess[2], 0.1)
  tau ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
  #transform
  sigma = 1/sqrt(tau)
}
"

#compiling 
mod_with = jags.model(textConnection(jags.script_with),
                      data = dataset,
                      n.chains = 4, n.adapt = 2000)
```

I can't figure out how to resolve the issue.

Looking for advice, please.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

I have removed all (for the model) "unnecessary" parts. This is now the corrected code - unfortunately I cannot figure out why the error still persists.

*Compiling model graph
Resolving undeclared variables
Deleting model*

*Error in jags.model(textConnection(jags.script_with), data = dataset,  :
RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 5.
Dimension mismatch in subset expression of y*

```
library(rjags)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

sports_raw = read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-03-29/sports.csv')

Sports2 =
  bind_rows(
    sports_raw %>%
      select(year, institution_name, sports, 
             participants = partic_women,
             revenue = rev_women,
             expenditure = exp_women) %>%
      mutate(gender=1), #women
    sports_raw %>%
      select(year, institution_name, sports, 
             participants = partic_men,
             revenue = rev_men,
             expenditure = exp_men) %>%
      mutate(gender=0) #men
  ) %>% na.omit

#modeling with regression
set.seed(123)

model_with =
  lm(expenditure ~ gender + participants, data=Sports2)

model_with

#dataset for jags model
dataset = list(x=Sports2[,c(4,7)], y=Sports2[,6], n=nrow(Sports2))


#estimation coefficients
dataset$b_guess = model_with$coefficients

#Model
jags.script_with =
  "
model{
  #likelihood
  for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
    mu[i] = intercept + participants*x[i,1]
  }
  #prioirs
  intercept ~ dnorm(b_guess[1], 0.1)
  participants ~ dnorm(b_guess[2], 0.1)
  tau ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
  #transform
  sigma = 1/sqrt(tau)
}
"

#compiling 
mod_with = jags.model(textConnection(jags.script_with),
                      data = dataset,
                      n.chains = 4, n.adapt = 2000)
```

Comment: `bgues[1]` should be `bguess[1]`.

Comment: thank you for flagging - it actually shoud be `b_guess[1]` 
However, even after correcting the spelling, the error message still pops up.

Comment: When I change `bgues[1]` to `b_guess[1]` the model initializes as it should.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong thank you for trying out! 
I have updated my question with the corrected and "clean" code. Is there anything that is catching your eye that might cause the error?
Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in your original code, you're subsetting a tibble using the `[` and unlike in a regular data frame, where it would turn that single column into a vector, the tibble remains a tibble with one variable.    The error really states that instead of being a vector as you intend in the model code, the `y` variable is actually a one-column data frame, which JAGS treats differently from a vector.

```
library(rjags)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

sports_raw = read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-03-29/sports.csv')

Sports2 =
  bind_rows(
    sports_raw %>%
      select(year, institution_name, sports, 
             participants = partic_women,
             revenue = rev_women,
             expenditure = exp_women) %>%
      mutate(gender=1), #women
    sports_raw %>%
      select(year, institution_name, sports, 
             participants = partic_men,
             revenue = rev_men,
             expenditure = exp_men) %>%
      mutate(gender=0) #men
  ) %>% na.omit

#modeling with regression
set.seed(123)

model_with =
  lm(expenditure ~ gender + participants, data=Sports2)

model_with

#dataset for jags model
dataset = list(x=Sports2[,c(4,7)], y=Sports2[,6], n=nrow(Sports2))
dim(dataset$y)
[1] 130748      1
```

There are two ways to fix this, you can make `y` a vector in the data:

```r
dataset = list(x=Sports2[,c(4,7)], 
               y=Sports2$expenditure, n=nrow(Sports2))
dim(dataset$y)
# NULL
length(dataset$y)
# [1] 130748
```

Or, you could change the likelihood part of your model to acknowledge that `y` is a one-column matrix:

```r
y[i,1] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
```

The rest of the model could stay as it is.  Do one or the other of these (though not both at the same time) and your model will run.